# How can I change the default sort order of the search results page in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the default sort order of the search results page in WooCommerce on our Wordpress site from Relevance to Popularity.

I found the below code from Ferguson230 on Github, I changed the term 'Best Sellers' to 'Popularity' and ran it through the Code Snippets plugin, it changes the terms in the drop down box but it doesn't automatically order the search results to Popularity first.

Can anyone advise how to change the code to work? I don't have any coding experience myself.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
/**
* @snippet       Remove Sorting Option @ WooCommerce Search
* @how-to        Get secure, fast, and discounted Wordpress hosting at https://turnuphosting.com/wordpress-hosting
* @author        Deedat
*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'dee_change_sorting_options_order', 5 );

function dee_change_sorting_options_order( $options ){

$options = array(

'popularity' => __( 'Sort by Best Sellers', 'woocommerce' ),

'date'       => __( 'Sort by latest', 'woocommerce' ),

'rating'     => 'Sort by average rating', // __() is not necessary
'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),
'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' ),

);

return $options;

}


/**
* @snippet       Remove Sorting Option @ WooCommerce Shop
* @how-to        Get a secure, fast, and discounted Wordpress hosting at https://turnuphosting.com/wordpress-hosting
* @author        Deedat
*/
 

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering' ) ) {
/**
* Output the product sorting options.
*/
function woocommerce_catalog_ordering() {
if ( ! wc_get_loop_prop( 'is_paginated' ) || ! woocommerce_products_will_display() ) {
return;
}
$orderby                 = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'popularity' ) ); // WPCS: sanitization ok, input var ok, CSRF ok.
$show_default_orderby    = 'popularity' === apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'popularity' );
$catalog_orderby_options = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(

'popularity' => __( 'Sort by Best Sellers', 'woocommerce' ),
'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),
'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),
'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),
'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' ),
) );

$default_orderby = wc_get_loop_prop( 'is_search' ) ? 'popularity' : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'popularity' );
$orderby         = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) : $default_orderby; // WPCS: sanitization ok, input var ok, CSRF ok.

if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'is_search' ) ) {
$catalog_orderby_options = array_merge( array( 'relevance' => __( 'Relevance', 'woocommerce' ) ), $catalog_orderby_options );

unset( $catalog_orderby_options['menu_order'] );
if ( 'menu_order' === $orderby ) {
$orderby = 'popularity';
}
}

if ( ! $show_default_orderby ) {
unset( $catalog_orderby_options['menu_order'] );
}

if ( ! $show_default_orderby ) {
unset( $catalog_orderby_options['relevance'] );
}

if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) ) {
unset( $catalog_orderby_options['rating'] );
}



wc_get_template( 'loop/orderby.php', array(
'catalog_orderby_options' => $catalog_orderby_options,
'orderby'                 => $orderby,
'show_default_orderby'    => $show_default_orderby,
) );
}
}
```

Comment: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/change-defaut-product-sorting.html

Comment: Thanks but I've tried that and it doesn't work for the search results page

Comment: Then you will have to go and look for a hook that allows to modify the search query. `woocommerce_product_pre_search_products` could be the right place, not entirely sure though.